# A scala implementation of the Java trim method

Tags: java, beginner, strings, scala

I'm a Scala beginner and looking at the `trim()` method of the Java API.  I noticed side effects, so I attempted to implement a functional version in Scala.

Here is the Java version:

```
public String trim() {
int len = count;
int st = 0;
int off = offset;      /* avoid getfield opcode */
char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

while ((st < len) && (val[off + st] <= ' ')) {
    st++;
}
while ((st < len) && (val[off + len - 1] <= ' ')) {
    len--;
}
return ((st > 0) || (len < count)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

My Scala version iterates over a string, and when it encounters a space char, the tail of the string is returned. The entire string is then reversed, so it can access the trailing whitespace. This new string is iterated over until a space char is encountered and the tail of this string is returned. This new string is then reversed again to maintain the original string order:

```
def trim(stringToTrim : String) : String = {
    def removePreString[String](list : List[String]) : java.lang.String = list match {

        case head :: tail => {
            if(head.toString.equals(" ")){
                removePreString(tail)
            }
            else {
                head.toString + tail.mkString
            }
        }
    }//end removePreString

    val preString =    removePreString(stringToTrim.toList)
    val reveresedString = preString.toList.reverse
    val reveresedPostString = removePreString(reveresedString)
  reveresedPostString.reverse

}//end trim
```

How can this code be improved?  Does it seem wasteful reversing the string twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No good idea about the concern of reversing the list twice. But you may

1. Let you inner function return a List instead of a string thus having less conversions from list to string and string to list.
2. Change your match to the following pattern (not tested):

   ```
   case " " :: tail => removePreString(tail)
   case _ => _
   ```

I just realize you could also use on a list `def dropWhile(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): List[A]` which drops longest prefix of elements that satisfy a predicate. You could then chain dropWhile not a space | reverse | dropwhile not a space | reverse...

Answer (score 2):

you can test for a whitespace in patter matching, an alternative version of your `removePreSign` method therefore could be written as:

```
def removePreString(list : List[Char]): String = list match {
  case ' ' :: tail => removePreString(tail)
  case _ => list.mkString
}
```

but as pgras noted, you can simply use `str.dropWhile(_ == ' ')` which avoids the whole `String <=> List` issue.

A possible way to do it without `reverse` and `dropWhile` using only recursion:

```
def trim(stringToTrim : String) : String = {
  def removeLeading(str: String): String =
    if (str startsWith " " ) removeLeading(str tail)
    else str

  def removeTrailing(str: String): String =
    if (str endsWith " ") removeTrailing(str dropRight 1 )
    else str

  removeTrailing(removeLeading(stringToTrim))
}
```

Comment: your function 'removePreString' does not work for Strings with trailing whitespace. e.g - "   this is a test   "

Comment: neither does the original function, it is just another way to achieve the same thing, but as noted above it is equivalent to dropWhile

Answer (score 1):

- Since left and right trim may be useful on their own, expose them.
- View `String`  as a list of `Char` instead of converting to `List[String]`
- The recursion creates a string at each step ! Take advantage of the rich library of methods for lists (and the like).
- For instance, reversing twice is fine as long you manipulate iterators.

Applying these advices leads to :

```
def trimLeft  (s: String) = s dropWhile ( _ == ' ' )
def trimRight (s: String) = (s.reverseIterator dropWhile ( _ == ' ' ))
                               .toSeq.reverseIterator mkString
val trim = trimLeft _ compose trimRight _
```

It you prefer to extract the sub-string of interest at once, there are fine functions to find the indices you need.